# How do I change this Apex Charts Angular Boxplot from Vertical to Horizontal?

Tags: angular, typescript, boxplot, apexcharts

I'm currently trying to use this apex charts boxplot: https://apexcharts.com/angular-chart-demos/box-whisker-charts/boxplot-scatter/, but I need it to be Horizontal, instead of Vertical. I know that following the documentation (https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/bar/), it should be very simple, just adding to the typescript the property plotOptions > bar > horizontal and set it as true. But it doesn't seem to work for this particular example. I've tried doing this change in the Sandbox they provide, and nothing happens to the chart. Does anybody know if this is really possible for this specific chart?

Update: For more context, I need this boxplot to be horizontal and to have the outliers displayed. I've tried to use the horizontal boxplot example too (sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/apx-boxplot-horizontal-es5rs?from-embed), and then tried to add the outliers using the following typescript code on the sandbox. But the outliers won't render.

```
 import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
    
    import {
      ChartComponent,
      ApexChart,
      ApexPlotOptions,
      ApexTitleSubtitle,
      ApexAxisChartSeries,
      ApexStroke
    } from "ng-apexcharts";
    
    export type ChartOptions = {
      series: ApexAxisChartSeries;
      chart: ApexChart;
      title: ApexTitleSubtitle;
      plotOptions: ApexPlotOptions;
      stroke: ApexStroke;
    };
    
    @Component({
      selector: "app-root",
      templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      @ViewChild("chart") chart: ChartComponent;
      public chartOptions: Partial<ChartOptions>;
    
      constructor() {
        this.chartOptions = {
          series: [
            {
              name:'box',
              type:'boxPlot',
              data: [
                {
                  x: "Category A",
                  y: 54
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              name:'outlier',
              type:'scatter',
              data: [
                {
                  x: "Category A",
                  y: 54
                }
              ]
            },
          ],
    
          chart: {
            height: 350,
            type: "boxPlot"
          },
          title: {
            text: "Horizontal BoxPlot Chart",
            align: "left"
          },
          plotOptions: {
            bar: {
              horizontal: true,
              barHeight: "50%"
            },
            boxPlot: {
              colors: {
                upper: "#e9ecef",
                lower: "#f8f9fa"
              }
            }
          },
          stroke: {
            colors: ["#6c757d"]
          }
        };
      }
    
      public generateDayWiseTimeSeries(baseval, count, yrange) {
        var i = 0;
        var series = [];
        while (i < count) {
          var y =
            Math.floor(Math.random() * (yrange.max - yrange.min + 1)) + yrange.min;
    
          series.push([baseval, y]);
          baseval += 86400000;
          i++;
        }
        return series;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [horizontal boxplot example](https://apexcharts.com/angular-chart-demos/box-whisker-charts/horizontal-boxplot/) provided? Are you able to share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Yes, but the thing is that I need the outliers for my chart... that's why I chose this example. I don't know if I can add outliers to the horizontal one, but it might be worth a shot

Comment: And about the reproducible example, I was trying to use the webpage's own sandbox (link here: https://codesandbox.io/s/apx-boxplot-scatter-q7p9w?from-embed) to se if it was really possible to change the boxplot's orientation